# Copy storage accounts and output connection strings

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I need to deploy N storage accounts and output connection strings as array or better comma separated unified string value. I found a very useful [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) on how to deploy multiple resources. Here is how I can create multiple storage accounts.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[concat(copyIndex(),'storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "properties": {},
            "copy": {
                "name": "storagecopy",
                "count": 3
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Now the problem is, there is no info on how to iterate through storage accounts to output connection strings. Did anybody do something like this? How can I iterate through deployed storage accounts and output connection strings?

Comment: I have similar ARM template and ran into the same issue. I don't believe output section supports copy iterator. Can you share more details about your scenario? Why do you need to output the connection strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a working ARM Template modified based on your sample template above.

It is able to output the list of **partial** storage accounts connection strings deployed through ARM template deployment in the deployment output, **without the storage account keys**.

This is due to a open and known issue: [listKeys not supported in variable #1503](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/1503) in ARM, where the **listKeys** to list the storage account key is not allowed to be used in a ARM Template variable.

Output:

> {   "connectionstrings": [
>       {
>         "connectionstring": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0storageojjbpuu4wl6r4;AccountKey="
>       },
>       {
>         "connectionstring": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=1storageojjbpuu4wl6r4;AccountKey="
>       },
>       {
>         "connectionstring": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=2storageojjbpuu4wl6r4;AccountKey="
>       }   ] }

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 3
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountConnectionStrings": {
      "copy": [
        {
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "count": "[parameters('storageAccountCount')]",
          "input": {
            "connectionstring": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', concat(copyIndex('connectionstrings'),'storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)), ';AccountKey=')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[concat(copyIndex(),'storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "copy": {
        "name": "storagecopy",
        "count": "[parameters('storageAccountCount')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "connectionStringsArray": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[variables('storageAccountConnectionStrings')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, listKeys can't really be used until the resource is actually created

Answer (score 4):

So several options:

1. you can use copy inside `variables` section to create a variable with copy.
2. you can create a deployments loop to construct a variable using iterator (effectively)
3. Turn storage account creation into a nested deployment and do 1 deployment = 1 storage account, this way you dont need to bother with copy anywhere
4. Copy in outputs might be available already, didnt test it for a very long time

But i suggest you take a step back, really, most of the time outputting anything from the ARM template is a waste of effort, as this information could be salvaged with powershell or azure cli with much less effort.